# У меня двумерный массив данных, как лучше создать для него таблицу в базе данных?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня около 19 ключей (список различных свойств плюс некоторые отдельные параметры). У каждого ключа (кроме некоторых, типа названия или id) есть два значения - определённый номер (который пользователь вводит) и строковое значение.

Примерно каждая запись выглядит так (сокращённый вариант):

[image: привер записи в бд]

У меня postgresql база данных. Как лучше организовать подобную таблицу? Если надо разделить на две таблицы то как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Я не понял, как выглядит запись.

Comment: Ну вот на картинке это как бы одна запись должна быть. id и profile name там всего по одному значению, а в остальных колонках по два сразу.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению никто ничего не посоветовал, поэтому пришлось изобретать велосипед. Создавать 3 таблицы не захотелось, так как очень много значений, поэтому решил выкрутиться массивом. Просто создаю атрибут character varying[], что как я понимаю означает строковый массив. Вот моя тестовая таблица:

[image: Пример таблицы]

Ключ zustand как раз и есть пример массива. И таких ключей у меня должно быть ещё 18 (вот почему я отказался от варианта из трёх таблиц).

Запись с массивом создаётся так:

```sql
INSERT INTO interpretation_profiles 
(profile_name, start_row, zustand) 
VALUES ('test profile', '5', ARRAY ['2', 'unknown'])
```

А получение данных (чтобы данные массива были отдельными переменными) происходит примерно так:

```sql
SELECT id, 
profile_name, 
start_row, 
zustand[1] as zustand_col, 
zustand[2] as zustand_def 
FROM interpretation_profiles
```

Если кто подскажет ещё более удобный вариант, буду благодарен. Но на данный момент это самое оптимальное, что мне пришло в голову.

Answer (score 0):

Если отдельные параметры присутствуют не у всех, а там может еще что либо в дальнейшем добавиться - вариант все в jsonb класть.

Comment: Стоило бы написать поподробнее. Насколько я представляю, этот формат довольно редкоиспользуемый и я не уверен, что его стоит рекомендовать просто так.